# Is there a way to map a Single to another Single if onError?

Tags: rx-java2, android-room

So the scenario is that I have a user table that may not have any user in it.

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user LIMIT 1")
    Single<UserEntity> getUser();
}
```

Because of RxRoom, if there's no user, the Single will trigger onError. In this case, I want to map this Single to another Single that pull user from server.

```
Single<UserEntity> getRemoteUser();
```

Currently, I'm thinking chain the Singles like this:

```
userDao.getUser()
       .subscribe(
               user -> {
                   Timber.e("found user");
               },
               throwable -> {
                   Timber.e(throwable.getMessage());
                   getRemoteUser().subscribe(....);
               });
```

But I'm wonder is there any better way to achieve this? Maybe something like this:

```
    userDao.getUser()
       .mapOnError(throwable -> getRemoteUser())
       .subscribe(
               user -> {
                   Timber.e("found user");
               },
               throwable -> {
                   Timber.e(throwable.getMessage());
               });
```

Comment: onErrorResumeNext( ) — instructs an Observable to emit a sequence of items if it encounters . https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators, refer another example here http://blog.danlew.net/2015/12/08/error-handling-in-rxjava/

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that.

Comment: You can also make your `getUser()` method return `Maybe` instead of `Single`, and use `switchIfEmpty()` method to switch to another `Single` that loads from server.

Comment: @mol I thought about using a `Maybe` as well. Is it practical to use `Maybe` for everything query that may return one or none object related to database?

Comment: I think generally it is a good practice to explicitly say that query can return 0 items, but it is up to you to decide whether it is convinient to use `Maybe` in your project. Also note that there are some methods, that allow to convert `Maybe` to another reactive types such as: `toObservable()`, `toSingle()`, `toFlowable()`.